# Where should I place DO property checks that require input from other objects?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, datamapper

I am trying to get my head around the structure of domain objects, data mappers and services, I am however struggling to grasp exactly what goes where.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14143690/1681418) question is very similar, but does not have an answer that helps.

**Should methods that require properties from several objects go into;**

1. The Domain Object, or
2. The Service class, or
3. neither...

I am concerned creating a heavy Service class, but this approach seems simpler than editing both the DO and the DataMapper I would otherwise need.

```
final class UserService extends ServiceAbstract
{
    public function user_is_admin($id)
    {
        // Build the user object
        $userMapper = $this->dataMapperFactory->build('user');
        $user = $this->domainObjectFactory->build('user');
        $user->id = $id;
        $userMapper->fetch($user);

        // Build the admin usergroup object
        $usergroup = $this->domainObjectFactory->build('usergroup');
        $usergroupMapper = $this->dataMapperFactory->build('usergroup');
        $usergroup->id = ADMIN_USERGROUP_ID;
        $usergroupMapper->fetch($usergroup);

        // Perform the actual check
        if(in_array($user->id, $usergroup->aMembers))
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you breaking the encapsulation for `$user` and `$userGroup` instances?

Comment: @tereško Excuse my ignorance, but I am not sure I understand your question, what am I breaking?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: @tereško I believe this is slightly off topic, but I assume you would like me to write $user->setId($id); in place of $user->id = $id;?

Comment: Which is why it was a comment and not a part of answer. Using this approach would mean one of two possibilities: either you are using `public` visibility for domain object's parameters or you are using magic `__set()` methods. Both of these tend to gave determent affect on application. Magic methods tend to become black holes of complexity and `public` parameters cause you to loose control over when and how values change in domain object while completely bypassing any validation and checks.

Comment: @tereško Consider __set removed from that class:) I'll keep my __get method for now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User.isAdmin() struck to my mind at first. But in your case, it seems that User and UserGroup together determine whether a User is admin. So we cannot put the responsibility in either the User or UserGroup.

I usually introduce a Specification object in this situation(Sorry, the example is written in Java).

```
public class AdminSpec {
   private SomeComponetToRetrieveUserGroup userGroup;

   public AdminSpec(SomeComponetToRetrieveUserGroup userGroup) {
       this.userGroup = userGroup;
   }

   public boolean isSatisfiedBy(User user) {
       // Perform the actual check
   }
}
```

Therefore, the domain objects are not corrupted by undesired responsiblities, and the domain logic still remains in the Domain layer (not in application services).

You can find more details about Specification Pattern in DDD book or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So AdminSpec.isSatisfiedBy would be called from the service class after injecting the usergroup object? I see how this will move responsibilities around, but it seems excessive to create classes for checks such as this, it would not be just this example, but pretty much any property that is defined by multiple objects. (The user->isAdmin is actually what I had until realising my mistake.)

Comment: @birdieblue Whether to add an extra specification class totally depends on is the advanage gained (decoupling) worth the cost(an extra class) in your application.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, IMHO, you are performing the authorization check at the wrong level (read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685039/727208) for more details). And the other thing is - you seem to be returning data to the controllers (or your regional equivalent) from the model layer. Such a `boolean` response would indicate, that you have application logic bleeding in your controllers.

If you want to stick you your current structure, then something like this would make more sense:

```
class UserService
{
    // .. snip
    public function someMethod( $id ) 
    {

        $userMapper = $this->dataMapperFactory->build('user');
        $groupMapper = $this->dataMapperFactory->build('user');

        $user = $this->domainObjectFactory->build('user');
        $user->setId($id);
        $group = $this->domainObjectFactory->build('usergroup');
        $group->setId( UserGroup::ADMIN_GROUP );

        $userMapper->fetch($user);
        $groupMapper->fetch($group);


        return $group->hasUser( $user );
    }

}
```

<kbd>my 2 cents</kbd>

Comment: Valid point, it would indeed bleed. This confirms my gut feel _something_ was wrong with my approach. I had a look to your linked post before, but will need to revisit it.

Comment: I will move the authorization part to the correct level, and no longer have functions such as this in the service class. **However**, I might still need to read the group memberships of a user at some other point (or any other similar property that is determined by several objects). I would think that the Specification object suggested by Hippoom [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17636886/1681418) then would be the way to go. Given your two answers, any additional comments to that?

Comment: Well .. there is one thing. Your current approach seems to indicate, that every user can belong to only one group. If you are 100% confident that this won't change, leave it as it is. Otherwise, you really might look into establishing `many-to-many` relation between users and groups.

Comment: Quite the opposite really, a user can be part of many different groups. Otherwise I would have had _the_ group as a property on the user object directly. I did however only use users and groups as an example. The main issue I had was really how to define an object's property when its value is compiled by several objects.